# Plotting in R: Probability mass function for a Poisson distribution

Tags: probability, graphing-functions, poisson-distribution

Suppose that I have a Poisson distribution with mean of 6. I would like to plot a probability mass function that includes an overlay of the approximating normal density.

This is what i have tried

```
plot( dpois( x=0:10, lambda=6 ))
```

this produces

[image]

which is wrong.

How do i go about this.

Comment: This belongs on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). I have flagged moderators to see if they can move it there. You could add some more details while we wait, though. For instance, you can make an edit to your question adding what were you _expecting_ to see, for instance in the form of a drawing.

Comment: To the extent software is used to accomplish a mathematical goal, questions can be on-topic here.  However as currently phrased it requires a bit of guesswork on the part of Readers to imagine what goal is being pursued and why the result shown "is wrong".  So I think there is some room to improve this Question and make it suitable for Math.SE.

Answer (score 3):

On the graph your $x$ values should start at $0$ not $1$.  You should also extend to the right slightly more (there is no upper limit on a Poisson distribution)

For the normal distribution you can produce a suitable density using the `curve` function.  In this case, it is presumably sensible to suppose you want to compare with a $N(\lambda, \lambda)$ distribution which has the same mean and variance as the Poisson distribution.  You may also want to extend to the left

You could try something like

```
plot(0:20, dpois( x=0:20, lambda=6 ), xlim=c(-2,20))
normden <- function(x){dnorm(x, mean=6, sd=sqrt(6))}
curve(normden, from=-4, to=20, add=TRUE, col="red")
```

looking something like

[image]

Comment: Nice (+1). Couldn't resist embellishments.

Answer (score 2):

Direct plotting of PDFs.

```
x = 0:20;  pdf = dpois(x, 6)
plot(x, pdf, type="h", lwd=3, col="blue", 
  main="PDF of POIS(6) with Approximating Normal Density")
abline(h=0, col="green2")
curve(dnorm(x, 6, sqrt(6)), lwd=2, col="red", add=T) # 'x' mandatory arg
```

[image]

Use large simulated Poisson sample to make histogram, controlling cutpoints for
integer data. Then plot approximating normal density.

```
y = rpois(10^6, 6);  up=max(y)
hist(y, prob=T, br=(-1:up)+.5, col="skyblue2", xlab="x", 
  main="Simulated Sample from POIS(6) with Normal Approximation")
curve(dnorm(x, mean(y), sd(y)), col="red", lwd=2, add=T)
```

[image]

How well does $\mathsf{Binom}(n=600, p=.01)$ fit results? Add a couple of lines of code to overlay points. (Maybe change header.)

```
w=0:36;  pdf=dbinom(w, 600, .01)
points(w, pdf, pch=19, col="darkgreen")
```

[image]